# Why are my image icons on JLabels pixelated at runtime but not in design mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, imageicon

left: design mode, right: running:

[image: left: design mode, right: running]

Every time I run my programme, with an image icon it becomes pixelated or blurry, and I can't find this same problem anywhere. The images look fine in design mode.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

I am using this line of code to get the image:

`private Image img_home = new ImageIcon(LoginFrame.class.getResource("Images/Home.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(128, 128, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);`

I work in Eclipse if this makes any difference.

I am still quite new to this, so I hope someone can help!